# Вывод значения с массива

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется массив

```
UnboundedElementsIterator Object
(
    [xmlList:protected] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [Sign] => смн
                    [Code] => TJS
                )

            [0] => 43
        )

    [elementsType:protected] => Array
        (
            [type] => complexType
            [name] => OtapiMoney
        )

    [position:UnboundedElementsIterator:private] => 0
)
$res = $item->GetMoney();
```

Хочу вывести значение **43**, но не получается. Делаю так:

```
print_r($res[0]);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php

Comment: это не массив, а объект, причем с приватными свойствами. Нужно посмотреть методы класса UnboundedElementsIterator и с их помощью достать нужные данные.

Comment: @MarselArduanov, спасибо нашел там есть такая конструкция: `public function __construct($xmlList, $elementsType){
        $this->xmlList = $xmlList;
        $this->elementsType = $elementsType;

        $this->position = 0;
    }` как правильно передать объекту если данные хранятся здесь `$res = $item->GetMoney()`

Comment: @mega94, этого кода недостаточно

Comment: `var_dump(get_class_methods(get_class($res)))` ?

Comment: @MarselArduanov, вот сам класс: tajshare.tj/download.php?file=30c7b7ae-1bb6-11e6-b89b-00e0815e47ee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что целевой объект является [итератором](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.iterator.php). А если это так, то для получения нужного значения достаточно выполнить вот такой код:

```
$res->rewind();
$value = $res->current();
```

Подробнее о методах [\Iterator::current](http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.current.php) и [\Iterator::rewind](http://php.net/manual/ru/iterator.rewind.php) можно почитать в оф. документации PHP.

Comment: Охх вот только что понял об этом, смотрел что там в `current()` с помощью  `get_class_methods(get_class($res))` а там asString сделал так: `$res = $item->GetMoney()->current()->asString()` значении выводился спасибо огромное